# Launch omxplayer for video from local HTML

Tags: video, omxplayer, kiosk

I'm building a simple HTML kiosk for a church. HTML5 playback is pretty bad, even on a Raspberry Pi 3. I'm wondering if there is a way to force the computer to open an a video anchor on the web page (hosted locally, not on the web) to use omxplayer rather than playing it back in the browser.

Any tips are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Kweb](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=40860) yet?  I'm delving into it now for the very same reason.  I've been searching for digital display/kiosk solutions that will allow me to play a video in a window of an html page.  I need live web content for the rest of the page, but the video can be a local stream.

Streaming a YouTube playlist in an iframe works (mostly), but depending on the browser (and I have tried many) it will either cause the pi to overheat, or it simply displays poorly.  Kweb says it has the ability to run omxplayer in an iframe.  From there you can stream a local playlist.  Stand-alone, omxplayer has had the smoothest playback for me on the Rpi3 (as you probabably already know).  So if I can get it in the iframe of an html page, I think that might be the answer.

Maybe that's your solution too?  I'll post an update if I can get it working properly.  Otherwise, maybe [Screenly](https://www.screenlyapp.com/) is a solution that could work for you?

Comment: Yeah, I looked at kweb, but it just looks awful. It's really bare bones, which is fine for home use (it streamed great) but not being able to style and make it look nice for a public display ruled it out.